# Custom Model train_step is never called

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to build and train a language model according to this example from the  [keras documentation](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/masked_language_modeling/)

My MaskedLanguageModel class looks like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE
)
loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="loss")


class MaskedLanguageModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def train_step(self, inputs):
        if len(inputs) == 3:
            features, labels, sample_weight = inputs
        else:
            features, labels = inputs
            sample_weight = None

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self(features, training=True)
            loss = loss_fn(labels, predictions, sample_weight=sample_weight)

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

        # Compute our own metrics
        loss_tracker.update_state(loss, sample_weight=sample_weight)

        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
        return {"loss": loss_tracker.result()}

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        # We list our `Metric` objects here so that `reset_states()` can be
        # called automatically at the start of each epoch
        # or at the start of `evaluate()`.
        # If you don't implement this property, you have to call
        # `reset_states()` yourself at the time of your choosing.
        return [loss_tracker]
```

I'm facing the issue, that the `train_step` function is never called. And my loss is always "0.0000e+00".

But when I comment out the following section the loss is updated and gets smaller.

```py
@property
def metrics(self):
    # We list our `Metric` objects here so that `reset_states()` can be
    # called automatically at the start of each epoch
    # or at the start of `evaluate()`.
    # If you don't implement this property, you have to call
    # `reset_states()` yourself at the time of your choosing.
    return [loss_tracker]
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69315741/6761285) train_step should automatically called when training the model via .fit(...)

What am I doing wrong?

(My tensorflow version is 2.1.0)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Always validate with newer versions, i.e run on colab for a quick test for the latest tf version.

Comment: IIRC customizing `train_step` was only added in a later version -- I found a blog post saying it was in 2.2. So update your TF and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the model in the latest version of tensorflow(2.10.0) with the train step mentioned as below

```
loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE
)
loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="loss")


class MaskedLanguageModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def train_step(self, inputs):
        if len(inputs) == 3:
            features, labels, sample_weight = inputs
        else:
            features, labels = inputs
            sample_weight = None

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self(features, training=True)
            loss = loss_fn(labels, predictions, sample_weight=sample_weight)

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

        # Compute our own metrics
        loss_tracker.update_state(loss, sample_weight=sample_weight)

        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
        return {"loss": loss_tracker.result()}

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        # We list our `Metric` objects here so that `reset_states()` can be
        # called automatically at the start of each epoch
        # or at the start of `evaluate()`.
        # If you don't implement this property, you have to call
        # `reset_states()` yourself at the time of your choosing.
        return [loss_tracker]
```

It works fine. please refer to this working [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/9c947acfcfef2b1b34a3c6567572957e). Thank You.